# Android - Convert a date into a Timestamp

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, timestamp

I have a `Date` object that I want to convert it back to a Timestamp, the logic behind that is the user can input a event date and then that input gets converted to it's corresponding Timestamp and then uploaded to `Firebase Firestore`.
I have to use this method to make the sorting easier and accurate, between a list of dates, the nearest one gets displayed to user.

I have the other way around (convert a Timestamp into a date) up and running

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000L);
String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", cal).toString();
```

How to reverse this algorithm to meet my requirements ?

Comment: `set...` => `get...` and `* 1000L` => `/ 1000L` and `format` => `parse` ? and order is parse, get, divide

Comment: what is your input ?

Comment: @Kilarn123 my input is a `Date date` (which can also be a `String`)

Comment: well if it is a `Date`, `yourDate.getTime()` return the time in millisecond. you can divide it by 1000 to get the timestamp equivalent of what you set (get the total seconds)

Comment: I will go ahead and try it, but since the `Timestamp` is actually the total number of seconds passed since the start of recording in 1970, I don't think that it's gonna work @Kilarn123

Comment: well, `calendar#setTimeInMillis()` works the same way. It sets the millis since 1970 too

Comment: It didn't work, the results are not accurate, to make this whole thing easier how to sort Date objects?

Comment: Date implements `Comparable` so you can use `compareTo()` so if you have an arrayList of Date, you can use `Collections.sort(dateList);`

Comment: If Firebase doesn’t have a datetime datatype, I recommend you store strings in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, for example `2019-05-14T13:21:45Z`. Provided that your dates are in the range from year 1 through 9999, such strings sort in chronological order. And unlike Unix timestamps are human readable.

Comment: The questions “How to sort dates?” and “How to convert a date to a Unix timestamp?” have been asked over and over. Please search before posting the same question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the documentation of **java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()** it will return the current time as UTC milliseconds **from epoch**.

According that, you could do something as

```
public long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
```

}

I've tested and it works perfectly.

```
class Main {

    public static long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTime(date);
        return cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
    }

    public static Date timeStampToDate(long timestamp) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000L);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long date = 1000;

        System.out.println("Time as Date: " + timeStampToDate(date));
        System.out.println("Time in timestamp: " + dateToTimestamp(timeStampToDate(date)));
    }

}
```

One test case that tests that the method really does the opposite than the one that you've in the question:

```
@Test
void testTimestampConversion() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

    // Present
    long expected = dateToTimestamp(cal.getTime());
    assertEquals(expected, dateToTimestamp(timeStampToDate(expected)));

    // Past
    long expectedPast = 1000;
    assertEquals(expectedPast, dateToTimestamp(timeStampToDate(expectedPast)));

    // Future
    Date future = cal.getTime();
    future.setYear(3000);
    long expectedFuture = dateToTimestamp(future);
    assertEquals(expectedFuture, dateToTimestamp(timeStampToDate(expectedFuture)));
}
```

Comment: so does it work on future and past dates as well as current dates??

Comment: I've created a test case and it looks like it works, at least until year 3000.